# Hyperledger fabcar sample fabric showing connect failed ERROR

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to install hyperledger and run chain code. I followed all the steps as directed [here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). But getting error

> error: [client-utils.js]: sendPeersProposal - Promise is rejected: Error: Connect Failed

while running the query.js.
[image]I have following active docker running[image]
Before running the `node query.js`, when i am running `npm install` its giving following warning : 
`npm WARN fabcar@1.0.0 No repository field.` Is this the problem. Can any one please help me out about where it is going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I have met the same error during run sample, it failed to connect. I fixed it with following steps:

1. get machine IP address with: `ifconfig`
2. replace `localhosts` in `query.js` with IP in #1

Example:

```
@@ -12,7 +12,7 @@ var options = {
     user_id: 'PeerAdmin',
     channel_id: 'mychannel',
     chaincode_id: 'fabcar',
-    network_url: 'grpc://localhost:7051',
+    network_url: 'grpc://****:7051',
};
```

Comment: i changed it. but still facing the same problem. When i am doing npm install in the fabcar directory, i am getting following warning : `npm WARN fabcar@1.0.0 No repository field.`

Comment: What's your npm version? I use the latest version 5.1.0

Comment: Angela's on the right path... you don't have fabcar, do you have all the pre-reqs?... you don't have dev-peer0.org1.example.com-fabcar-1.0. I'm using npm 3.10.10

Comment: my npm version is 5.1.0. But still getting the error

Comment: I'm also facing this problem after changing this

Comment: I'm not sure what happened, but it works as expected when I redownload everything.

Answer (score 2):

Addition to Angela's answer:

To anyone having this issue and using Docker Toolbox, do `docker-machine ls` and copy the IP adress at the URL column of your ACTIVE machine and paste the IP adress to every `localhost` in both `query.js` and `invoke.js` files.

Comment: Wait for upto 90 seconds, it will work. For me after 90 seconds i got chaincode installation failed. I started again it worked. [Screenshot] (https://imgur.com/a/DbO708o)

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that error occur when `datasources.json` specifies that the network addresses start with `grpcs://`, but the network is not set up to use TLS. Try changing them to start with `grpc://`.

Answer (score 0):

Do `docker-machine ls`

**Output**:

> $ docker-machine ls NAME ACTIVE DRIVER STATE URL SWARM DOC default 
>   virtualbox Running tcp://192.168.99.100:2376 v17

- copy the ip address mentioned , like : 192.168.99.100
- go to \fabric-samples\fabcar\query.js
- replace the localhost with the IP address